# Align multiple legends with patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

In [this vignette](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html#controlling-guides) of [patchwork](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patchwork/index.html) is explained how to combine multiple ggplots. One difficulty I encountered is to collect the legends and align/justify them properly when their titles are very different in number of characters.

Below is an example - I would like the 'mpg' legend to be also left justified / aligned and not centered beneath the 'Size' legend. Any suggestions? Note that, adding `theme(legend.justification = "left")` doesn't solve the problem.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp, colour = mpg, size = wt)) + 
  guides(size = guide_legend(title = "Size - long title for the purpose of this example")) +
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')

(p1 | (p2 / p3)) + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh, actually this seems to be an [opened issue](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/pull/140)

Comment: Workaround: Add linefeeds to the long title. `title = "Size - long title for\\nthe purpose of this example"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the meantime, [this was fixed by Ilia Kats](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/pull/140).

Using  `& theme(legend.justification = "left")` (when keeping legends separate/aligned with plot) or `+ plot_layout(guides = 'collect')` (merging legends from plots) now just works.

Use `remotes::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")` to update `patchwork` (if pre ~2020).

---

Detailed example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp, colour = mpg, size = wt)) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(title = "Size - long title for the purpose of this example")) +
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) +
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) +
  ggtitle('Plot 3')
```

OP's case is fixed:

```r
(p1 | (p2 / p3)) + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]

But the default case is still not aligned:

```r
(p1 / p3)
```

[image]

Align by merging guides (now fixed):

```r
(p1 / p3) + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]

Align by left justification (now fixed):

```r
(p1 / p3) & theme(legend.justification = "left")
```

[image]
(This would be desirable if there are no shared legends between the two plots ( so this just an bad example for the use))

<sup>Created on 2020-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```
# Session info: 
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06),            
 ggplot2     * 3.3.1      2020-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                        
 patchwork   * 1.0.1.9000 2020-09-10 [1] Github (thomasp85/patchwork@82a5e03)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It seems that the bug was indeed fixed, no need for even adding `theme(legend.justification = "left")` after  `(p1 | (p2 / p3)) + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')` (in my example above, at least). Maybe would be nicer if you edit your answer so that it applies to the code I already provide and is not just a print screen of the GitHub issue/pull request page.

Comment: @Valentin good to know, I extended the anwer accordingly

Comment: note, [this seems to fail when using `theme_void()`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/237) -