# Horizontal alignment of colour scales in patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I'm using the package `patchwork` to combine multiple `ggplot2` plots vertically. I'd like the scales for each plot to be directly above one another, regardless of the length of the scale name. At the moment, the scales are not aligned above one another.

I'm open to using `ggpubr` or `facet_grid()` if they would make it possible, but I've seen that facets [doesn't allow multiple scales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809071/3379675), and I haven't found any solution using `ggpubr`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(0)
testdata <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, col=runif(10))

g1 <- ggplot(testdata, aes(x=x,y=y,col=col)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_color_gradient(name="Short")
g2 <- ggplot(testdata, aes(x=x,y=y,col=col)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_color_gradient(name="A rather longer name")
g1/g2

ggsave("testfile.tiff", units = "mm", device="tiff", 
       width=100, height=100, dpi = 100)
```

[image: Example plot with scales not aligned]

Ideal output:

[image: Example plot with scales aligned]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align multiple legends with patchwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59360162/align-multiple-legends-with-patchwork)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `plot_layout` you can "collect" the legends. This uses as default `theme(legend.position = 'right')`. You can add this after plot_layout with `& theme(legend.position = 'right')` and adjust the position if you want to change the location of the legends.

```
g1/g2 + plot_layout(guides = 'collect') # & theme(legend.position = 'right') <- adjust position here!

ggsave("testfile.tiff", units = "mm", device="tiff", 
       width=100, height=100, dpi = 100)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, I encourage the question asker to prefer this answer over mine.

Comment: I don't seem to be seeing the expected effect here. Running `g1/g2 + plot_layout(guides="collect")` moves the bottom guide up, and top guide down so they're closer together, but doesn't change their horizontal alignment.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `theme(legend.box.just = 'left')` - that seems to solve it

Comment: @Miff, On my machine everything works out of the box, but it is a clean session. ` & theme(legend.box.just = 'left')` or `& theme(legend.position = 'right')` all show the same as the picture above. If the legends are the same except for the title, you might want to look rename the title to combine them all into 1 legends. Or you might look into `guide_area` for collecting all the legends in 1 place in the graph space.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also be curious to learn of a patchwork parameter than could fix this, but I don't think there is one (please correct me if I'm wrong). You may have noticed that Hadley's answer is more than 10 years old and people have been working on ggplot2 since then. The `ggnewscale` package solves the problem of having multiple scales per plot. Here is a facetted approach using multiple colourscales:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

set.seed(0)
testdata <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, col=runif(10))

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y, y)) +
  geom_point(data = transform(testdata, 
                              facet = factor("Top", c("Top", "Bottom"))),
             aes(colour = col)) +
  scale_colour_continuous(name = "Short") +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_point(data = transform(testdata,
                              facet = factor("Bottom", c("Top", "Bottom"))),
             aes(colour = col)) +
  scale_colour_continuous(name = "A rather longer name") +
  facet_wrap(~ facet, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This correctly addresses the problem, but has the disadvantage that the scales don't vertically match well with the plots with more than a couple of facets.